# Gnuplot shifted x-axis

Tags: alignment, gnuplot, horizontal-scaling

Hello I have following gnuplot example data in 3 files:

```
format kompression avgcover avgdiff1 avgdiff2
jp2 10 95.68 3.74 4.02
jp2 20 95.63 3.79 4.01
jp2 30 95.62 3.80 3.92
jp2 40 95.81 3.61 3.79
jp2 50 96.13 3.29 3.72
jp2 60 96.59 2.83 3.64
jp2 70 96.76 2.66 3.25
jp2 80 97.05 2.37 2.99
jp2 90 97.17 2.25 2.83
jp2 100 97.24 2.18 2.52

format kompression avgcover avgdiff1 avgdiff2
jpg 10 95.12 2.25 2.83
jpg 20 95.23 3.79 4.01
jpg 30 95.34 2.66 3.25
jpg 40 95.23 3.61 3.79
jpg 50 96.16 3.64 3.72
jpg 60 96.86 2.83 2.37
jpg 70 96.23 2.66 3.25
jpg 80 97.12 2.37 3.64
jpg 90 97.44 2.25 2.83
jpg 100 97.24 2.18 2.52

format kompression avgcover avgdiff1 avgdiff2
jxr 10 95.12 2.25 2.83
jxr 20 95.23 3.79 4.01
jxr 30 95.34 2.66 3.25
jxr 40 95.23 3.61 3.79
jxr 50 96.16 3.64 3.72
jxr 60 96.86 2.83 2.37
jxr 70 96.23 2.66 3.25
jxr 80 97.12 2.37 3.64
jxr 90 97.44 2.25 2.83
jxr 100 97.24 2.18 2.52
```

Now I have the following gnuplot command:

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set xlabel "Kompression"
set ylabel "Wert"
set size 1,1
set yrange[90:100]
set y2range[0:10]
set y2tics
set ytics nomirror
set key outside right top
set style data histogram
set style fill solid border -1
set output 'test.eps'
set key outside right top
set style line 1 lt 1 lw 3 pt 2 lc rgb "red"
set style line 2 lt 1 lw 1 pt 1 lc rgb "orchid"
set style line 3 lt 1 lw 3 pt 2 lc rgb "blue"
set style line 4 lt 1 lw 1 pt 1 lc rgb "light-turquoise"
set style line 5 lt 1 lw 3 pt 2 lc rgb "dark-green"
set style line 6 lt 1 lw 1 pt 1 lc rgb "greenyellow"
plot './ergebnisse/outputFDSQL_jp2.dat' using 3:xtic(2) ls 1 
    title'JP2(cov)' axis x1y1, '' u 4 ls 2 title 'JP2(notc)' axis x1y2, '' u 5 ls 2   
    title 'JP2(morc)'axis x1y2, './ergebnisse/outputFDSQL_jpg.dat' using 3:xtic(2) ls 3 
    title 'JPG(cov)' axis x1y1 , '' u 4 ls 4 title 'JPG(notc)' axis x1y2, '' u 5 ls 4 
    title 'JPG(morc)' axis x1y2, './ergebnisse/outputFDSQL_jxr.dat' using 3:xtic(2) ls 
    5 title 'JXR(cov)' axis x1y1 , '' u 4 ls 6 title 'JXR(notc)' axis x1y2, '' u 5 ls 6 
    title 'JXR(morc)' axis x1y2
```

This results in the following outputfile:

[image: test.eps]

Here you can see that the values from 0-100 on the x-axis are shifted not correct, does anybody see the error in the code?

Comment: Could you please tell us what you are trying to achieve? What do you want to plot *exactly*?

Comment: the only thing that i am allowed to say is that the x axis has moved a little bit to the right without any reason.. the values for it starts at 10 so i really cant figure out why this happens

Comment: I don't mean for you to reveal your company secrets or whatever, just what column of your data set is the x value and which one is the y value? E.g., if you're plotting column 4 against column 2 your should use `u 2:4`.

Comment: thank you :) so the x axis is column 2 (10-100) and the y1(90-100) axis column 3 and the y2(0-10) axis is based on column 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code, the data your posted and your codes gives me this:

[image]

Can you think of anything else you are doing?

Edit:

The file headers were messing up your graph, which were not posted originally with the data. You can comment them out, rather than delete them. Use `#` before the commented text.

Comment: There are 3 files.. try it with 3 please.. 
just replace the jp2 in the first file with jpg and in the second with jxr

Comment: @StefanSprenger No change, the histogram boxes are still centered. What is your gnuplot version? Also, when you say that the other files only differ in the first column, this is clearly not the case in your figure, for which the 3 different data files give different profiles.

Comment: gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 3

Comment: @StefanSprenger I have tested it both on gnuplot 4.6 pl 4 and your version, 4.4 pl 3, both work fine. Maybe post your other files?

Comment: Edited my post, but they have the same format.. Try my code exact with the 3 files pls i start with this command gnuplot foo.plt

Comment: @StefanSprenger I edited my answer, but the figure still comes up OK. Note that the values on your figure are different. Are you plotting something else?

Comment: could you post your .plt file? or didn't you change anything?

Comment: @StefanSprenger I only added backslashes to your `plot` command for line breaks, nothing else.

Comment: in every file on top is a headline, maybe this is important? format kompression avgcover avgdiff1 avgdiff2

Comment: jesus christ .. ^^ you can add to answer that I should delete headlines of files ^^ i will accept your answer thanks for your help, I'm so sorry for forgetting to mention this

Comment: @StefanSprenger xD No worries.